# REST API, как защитить приложение от взлома

Tags: android, api, rest

Всем привет.
Есть приложение которое обращается к АПИ с grant_type: client_credentials.
У данного клиента есть доступы ко многим ресурсам (получить всех пользователей, все заказы и пр.)

В момент передачи все идет через https и оттуда client_id и client_secret угнать не получится.

Однако эти данные хранятся в самом приложении, а значит если как-то распаковать приложение, то злоумышленник сможет получить доступ ко всему апи.

Как от этого защититься?

Comment: адрес апи у вас хранится где?

Comment: также в приложении